# Transformar String em LocalDateTime

Tags: java, angular, typescript, datetime

Criei este botão de Editar Campos, para alterar os dados desses usuários que criei, o nome, nome embossado e documento estão funcionando, sem a data de nascimento é feito a atualização, porém quando tento editar a Data de Nascimento, vem um bad request, pois o formulário espera uma `LocalDateTime`, como faço pra transformar essa String em `LocalDateTime`?

[image: Campo Data Nascimento]

[image: Bad request]

EDIT:

O get da Data de Nascimento.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

EDIT 2: Pode ser isto então eu estou manipulando apenas no front

```
    editarAdicional(item: any) {

    this.edicaoAdicionais.idPessoa = item.idPessoa;
    this.edicaoAdicionais.nomeCompleto = item.nomeCompleto;
    this.edicaoAdicionais.nomeEmbossado = item.nomeEmbossado;
    this.edicaoAdicionais.dataNascimento = this.formataDatas(item.dataNascimento);
    this.edicaoAdicionais.documento = item.documento;

    this.editandoAdicionais = true;
}

atualizarAdicional(item: any) {
    let formatador = new Formatadores();

    item.idPessoa = this.edicaoAdicionais.idPessoa;
    item.nomeCompleto = this.edicaoAdicionais.nomeCompleto;
    item.nomeEmbossado = this.edicaoAdicionais.nomeEmbossado;
    let dataNascimento = formatador.parseDate(this.edicaoAdicionais.dataNascimento);
    item.dataNascimento = dataNascimento.toISOString();
    item.documento = this.edicaoAdicionais.documento;

    this.editandoAdicionais = false;
```

Comment: "25/07/1981" é o que vc manda pro backend Java e lá ele tenta transformar em `LocalDateTime`? E o get que retorna "1981-07-25T00:00:00" é o que ele retorna qdo já existe uma data lá?

Comment: "25/07/1981" é a data formatada do get, eu preciso mandar ela como String e transformar como LocalDateTime, posso ter feito besteira quanto a isso, porque não entendo muito bem de como manipular datas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Um [`LocalDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html) precisa da data e hora para ser criado, mas a `String` que você manda ("25/07/1981") só possui a data.

Uma opção para resolver isso no código Java seria fazer o *parsing* desta data e colocar um horário qualquer. Para isso usamos um [`java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html):

```java
String s = "25/07/1981";
DateTimeFormatter parser = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/uuuu");
// faz o parsing e setar o horário para meia-noite
LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDate.parse(s, parser).atStartOfDay();
System.out.println(dateTime); // 1981-07-25T00:00
```

Primeiro eu crio um [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) (já que a `String` original só tem dia, mês e ano) e em seguida eu uso o método [`atStartOfDay()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#atStartOfDay--), que retorna um `LocalDateTime` com o horário setado para meia-noite. Você também pode usar [`atTime(10, 30)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#atTime-int-int-) para setar o horário para 10:30 da manhã, por exemplo. Use o que for melhor para o seu caso.

Outra opção é usar um [`java.time.format.DateTimeFormatterBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatterBuilder.html), juntamente com um [`java.time.temporal.ChronoField`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/ChronoField.html) para setar o valor do horário para meia-noite. Com isso, não é mais necessário criar o `LocalDate`, pois podemos criar o `LocalDateTime` diretamente:

```java
String s = "25/07/1981";
DateTimeFormatter parser = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
    // dia/mês/ano
    .appendPattern("dd/MM/uuuu")
    // valor default para o horário (zero para meia-noite)
    .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0).toFormatter();
LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(s, parser);
System.out.println(dateTime); // 1981-07-25T00:00
```

Setando a hora para zero, o horário do `LocalDateTime` será meia-noite (os minutos, segundos e frações de segundos podem ser omitidos, pois serão automaticamente setados para zero).

---

Com isso você não muda o tipo do campo nem o código do *frontend*. Embora eu ache melhor - se for possível - usar apenas `LocalDate` no *backend*, pois você só está guardando a data de nascimento (dia, mês e ano), e o horário parece não importar neste caso. Claro que isso vai exigir uma alteração no *frontend*, pois a data retornada estará sem o horário (será apenas `1981-07-25`).